# Telerik grid custom binding: how should it look in 2014 (documentation seems to be outdated)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm new to Telerik controls. I've read the documentation on [Telerik grid custom binding](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-custom-binding.html) and tried to implement a sample application using it. The documentation seems to be outdated. But the most confusing thing is that if I understand correctly, some classes related to custom binding were removed/replaced, while other remain in the library:

- `GridActionAttribute` now is not present in `Kendo.Mvc.dll`
- `GridModel` was removed.
- `GridCommand` remains in place and not marked as obsolete. **What for?** It seems it can't be used without `GridModel` and `GridAttribute`, at least i couldn't make it working without them. There is a new class now `DataSourceRequest` which is a duplicate of `GridCommand` by internal structure, but different in usage.
- Extention method of Grid configuration `EnableCustomBinding(true)` is still in place, and it is not marked as obsolete. But my implementation of custom binding works equivalently with or without it. I'm not sure if my implementation is correct though =).

Unfortunately I couldn't find any updated examples on the web - the majority was posted in 2011-2012 using approach with `GridActionAttribute`.

Now, let me provide my implementation of custom binding. It is very simple and incomplete (just for example):

```
public ActionResult CustomGrid([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    return Json(new DataSourceResult {
                                         Data = GetPeople().Skip((request.Page - 1)*request.PageSize).Take(request.PageSize).Select(PersonToModel), 
                                         Total = GetPeople().Count()
                                     }, 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So basically I've just made my own implementation of the `ToDataSourceResult` method. But this will allow me issuing custom requests to remote services now. It is working find for me. But is it a correct nowadays approach to custom bindings?

As I said, calling `EnableCustomBinding(true)` on grid or missing it doesn't make any effect on the work of my example. So I'm a bit confused about this method too, if my implementation is correct.

**To sum up, my questions are:**

1. Is my implementation a correct way of making custom binding now? [**Update**: yes]
2. If yes, why some old classes and methods of custom binding still exists and not marked as obsolete?
3. Is there any updated documentation, or change notes? I see functionality is changing constantly and such questions probably will appear quite often. [**Update**: [here is an updated documentation]](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding)

**UPDATE:**
My assumption was correct. I found an [updated documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/custom-binding) on custom binding and it is described exactly as I assumed. So only 2nd question is active now.

Comment: I've been fighting with their grid for a while now, and am still non the wiser about the ajax stuff. If you get this going, could you share? I've just ended up using the scaffolding and then calling table to be a kendo grid

Comment: @jbutler483, I'm investigating Telerik grid for 2nd day only. But I didn't have problems with Ajax requests for now. The video http://www.telerik.com/videos/aspnet-mvc/-persistedvalue-kendo-ui-for-asp-net-mvc-grid-value-kendo-ui-for-asp-net-mvc-grid- was helpful and worked for me.

Comment: I think the problem is that they've several different ways of doing the same thing (html5/mvc samples are different) and yet they're not? Now i'm not exactly fluent in ajax (at all, really), but they docs do seem to be a bit confusing/misleading at the best of times

Comment: @jbutler483, agree, documentation isn't a great helper. Also I found out that some combinations of configuration methods doesn't work together (for example, ClientRowTemplate() with Column().Format() etc). While finally it seems logical (one is for client binding, another - for server), it should be said somewhere in documentation, or not allow to make such configurations at all, throwing exceptions. Anyway, practice is all we need. The functionality itself looks powerful, just confusing in some ways.